Let $T$ be a regular tree. Must every non-trivial $H\times K \subset \text{Aut}(T)$ have a fixed point in $T \cup \partial T$?
Let $T$ be a locally finite (simplicial) regular tree of degree $d\geq3$, let $G$ be a group which acts effectively on $T$ by isometries (and sending vertices to vertices and edges to edges). Let us suppose that there exists a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ of the form $H \times K<G$, with $H \neq 1$ and $K \neq 1$. Is it true then that $Fix(H\times K)\neq \emptyset$ ? With $Fix(\bullet)$ I mean the fixed points of the action in both $T$ and the boundary of $T$, but here I am more concerned if there exists a fixed point of $H \times K$ which is an actual vertex of $T$. I guess that probably the reason why I think this is a reasonable statement comes from an intuition in hyperbolic geometry, but maybe I am completely off track.

You probably mean that the $G$-action is effective and $H\ne 1, K\ne 1$. Do you know about $G=PSL(2, \mathbb Q_p)$ acting on a simplicial tree? What about stabilizers of points at infinity of that tree?

@MoisheKohan absolutely! I added the missing hypotheses in the question. Unfortunately I don't know the action you are referring to, I am trying to look for some info online but I am not finding the info about the stabilizers. Could you please indicate a reference for it?

Then you should read Serre's book "Trees."

It is not true for trees or hyperbolic space.
The counterexample is easier to construct in $\mathbb{H}^2$. Let $\ell \subset \mathbb{H}^2$ be some oriented line. Then $D_\infty$, the infinite dihedral group, acts on $\ell$ and extends to an isometric action on $\mathbb{H}^2$. Let $\tau$ denote the reflection through $\ell$. Since $\tau$ commutes with every element of $D_\infty$, we have a copy of $D_\infty \times\langle \tau \rangle$ inside $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^2)$ without any fixed points.
A similar construction works for trees. To write this down completely would be tricky, but the idea is the same. Let $T$ have valence 4. Take a line $\ell \subset T$, and draw the tree in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that

$\ell$ lies on the $x$-axis, and each vertex on $\ell$ lies on an integer point $(n, 0)$
vertices adjacent to $\ell$ but not on $\ell$ lie on points $(n, 1)$ or $(n,-1)$
The drawing is otherwise as symmetric as possible: translation to the right by 1 is a symmetry, and reflection over the $x$ and $y$ axes are symmetries.

Then there is a copy of $D_\infty$ (translation left-right, and reflection over $y$-axis) and a reflection over the $x$-axis, $\tau$. These commute in $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, so they certianly commute in $\text{Aut}(T)$. As before, this gives a $D_\infty \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \subset \text{Aut}(T)$ without fixed points.
